# Uninstall Android Apps From My App

Tags: android, uninstallation

Is there any way to uninstall an app from my app?I have tried like below but app crashed with exception.

```
Uri packageUri = Uri.parse(items.get(
Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())).getPname());
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Logcat:-

```
11-01 11:14:35.781: E/AndroidRuntime(3834): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=com.android.gesture.builder }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i did not get you actually what you want ? as i got that you want to uninstall your app using code with your app is it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Delete application you must know the package name of the Application.

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.android.myapp");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

**Edit :**

```
Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+items.get(
Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())).getPname());
```

Comment: @user1767260 i think there will be problem with package name.

Comment: com.android.gesture.builder is the package name and I have used the same for launching the app

Comment: @user1767260 Try with this . Uri.parse("package:com.android.gesture.builder"); and see what happns

Comment: not working for me..do u we have provide in the AndroidManifest.xml file?